# Saving a DataFrame in a specific google drive folder in Google Colab

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm created a dataframe in Google Colab

I wan' to save it (as a google sheets or excel file) in a specific folder within my google drive or my local disk

I've searched everywhere but I haven't been able to understand the explanations and solving what I want

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.to_excel('df.xlsx')
from google.colab import files
files.download('df.xlsx')
```

Comment: In the first line - where does that file actually go? somewhere on google drive?

Comment: It downloads the file to your browser, so you can save to your local disk.